# How to stop infinite scroll in discretescrollview

Tags: android, android-studio, infinite-scroll

https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView

I tried a lot but i cannot stop the infinite scroll. If somebody knows about that, Kindly tell me

Comment: We normally require you to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Set your Parent Layout (LinearLayout) height wrap_conent. 
The discretescrollview
is set to wrap_content, but its child is set to fill_parent. This makes no sense, as something needs to provide a size.

Happy coding!!